# Flows - Record Update - Separate Order Of Execution per Update?

Tags: apex, process-builder, visual-workflow

I'd like to be sure, as my testing so far is inconclusive:

**When you have a Flow that performs TWO record updates (on the same object, same record), are they separate Orders Of Execution?**  Meaning, does the first record update COMPLETE and SAVE, prior to the second record update happening?

[image: Simple Flow with two Record Updatees]

If NOT, is there a way to **"fully commit" (SAVE) a record update prior** to another one inside the same Flow?

And does the same answer apply to other things such as query (Lookup)?  Each block is a separate Query and completes prior to the next block running?

Comment: Is your concern around referencing record1 in record2? Flow is able to do that without any problem.

Comment: No.  My concern is that I need a set of updates to Record 1 to be fully commited to the database, prior to the SECOND SET of updates to Record 1.  There is no record 2.   I'm probably going to end up with some Apex which we'll outsource, because I'm not supposed to be developing and in a Rootstock world, anything I write could be broken by the smallest of changes after it works the first time.    -Thanks.

Comment: I probably have four variations of this question over the past 3 years on StackExchange;  Rootstock has just made it 10x worse in my currently org.

Comment: Gotcha.  Im not familiar w rootstock, but one surprising functionality I ran into recently that you may want to test is that when I had a fast update and a record update on the same object in a single flow, the fast update ran before the record update even though they were in the reverse order.  I doubt it would be a full commit and don't believe it's documented, but you could have a go of it.  Apex is prob the best bet.

Answer (score 3):

Everything that occurs between one screen and the next in a flow occurs in the same transaction, just as it would be in Visualforce. While each record will go from beginning to "end" of the [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) documentation, the final commit and post-commit logic cannot execute until either a screen is reached, or the last element runs successfully. IF you absolutely need some time between, you'd have to insert a screen (for Visual Flows) or a Wait element (for Auto-Launched Flows) so that the transaction can wrap up and resume later.

You could prove this to yourself with a simple experiment. Create a flow that creates 200 records one at a time, inserting each one. You'll hit governor limits before you get all the way through the flow.

Comment: Great answer; I should have clarified auto-executed Flows.  I'm going to play with Wait first.  What about a Flow calling another Flow?  It seems nearly impossible (I know it's not in APEX) to cause TWO updates to happen to a record (separate saves) without going directly to Apex.

Comment: @AMM Well, you can update the record more than once (it'll trigger all logic twice), but it'll still be within the same transaction, meaning if the second save failed it would also unravel the first save as well.

Comment: I honestly have given up.  We are ending up hiring a Rootstock expert consultant AND a Consultant to help offset some of my SF setup duties, due to the complexity of things in a Rootstock centric world.   I can't write Process Builders or Flows or Workflows without tripping Rootstock most of the time, which itself has code "everywhere" touching objects all over the place.